# Default implied time for comparison in Oracle SQL TO_DATE?

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm doing a SQL query in Oracle 10g where I'm comparing against a cutoff date.  So my query has this in it:

```
THING < TO_DATE('02/14/13','MM/DD/YY')
```

Now the THING can have a time component in it.  I want to know how the cutoff date will interact with it.  Does the TO_DATE function have some default implied time component in it?  Does the date it creates have a default time of midnight on the specified date, or noon or some other time?  Essentially my concern is if I have a column in the table like this:

```
THING
-------
2/4/13 11:13AM
2/13/13 3:36PM
2/14/13 2:00PM
2/15/13 1:52AM
```

Will I get 2 rows or 3 rows back?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The implied time is 00:00:00, so in your example you will get two rows back.

You can verify this with:

```
select to_char(TO_DATE('02/14/13','MM/DD/YY'),'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS')
from   dual;
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll get two rows back. The implied time is 0:00:00 (midnight). Your dates with a 24-hour clock look like this:

```
2/13/13 3:36PM                 --> 2013-02-13 15:36:00
TO_DATE('02/14/13','MM/DD/YY') --> 2013-02-13 00:00:00
```